# Azure AD B2C's signature cannot be validated for tokens issued by Microsoft Graph API

Tags: jwt, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, azure-authentication

It's been three days that I have been trying to find a solution for the exception that I am getting for the following code to validate a Graph API token:

```cs
 var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                            $"{_authenticationSettings.Authority}/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                            new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
                        var config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();
                        _validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            // Audience MUST be the app ID aka clientId
                            ValidAudience = _authenticationSettings.ClientId,
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidIssuer = config.Issuer,
                            ValidateLifetime = true
                        };

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var result = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authHeader.Parameter, _validationParameters, out var jwtToken);
```

The exception happens when calling `ValidateToken` and reads as below:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException:
> 'IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried:
> 'System.Text.StringBuilder'.  kid: 'System.String'.  Exceptions
> caught:  'System.Text.StringBuilder'. token:
> 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken'.'

I am really running out of reasons why this should happen. Any ideas or suggestions to fix this problem?

The packages are:

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.8.0" />
```

Even [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865103/get-error-idx10511-signature-validation-failed-when-trying-to-validate-an-azu) was not conclusive too.

Comment: It would seem to me that the trouble is around the `config.SigningKeys` - I just tried your same code, and mine is working as expected with a valid `jwtToken` output upon validation.

Comment: What's the solution then?

Comment: Are you sure the Token is coming from the same source as the `{_authenticationSettings.Authority}` OpenID metadata link? I would compare the token in `authHeader.Parameter` and the signing keys that you get in `config.SigningKeys`

Comment: Yes, 100% is from the very same source.

Comment: Does the token look alright if you throw it in https://jwt.ms? And is the `kid` the one that you're getting in your `config.SigningKeys`?

Comment: I forgot to mention it. jwt.io says that the signature is invalid. Other fields seem all right though.

Comment: You will need to convert your JWK to a PEM if you want to validate the signature with jwt.io - To get your JWKs https://tenantname.b2clogin.com/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=b2c_1a_policyname

Then convert to a PEM using https://8gwifi.org/jwkconvertfunctions.jsp

Comment: By the way, the generated token is a Graph API token to validate.

Comment: Do I need to do the same PEM changes in C#?:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229107/discussion-between-brad-c-and-arash).

Comment: What is the value of _authenticationSettings.Authority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph API tokens cannot and should not be validated and hence the signature validation fails. Please see [this answer on GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/609#issuecomment-524434987).

Answer (score 0):

Validating a Token from the Graph API is a bit different than a standard OIDC Token.

See the following for more information:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/609

Comment: That makes sense. I have added "/.default" to the scope but I still get the error. I will keep trying later on today and update this post accordingly.

Comment: I added /.default to the app ID URI but it was not conclusive either.